# How to generate eIDAS certificate for Payoneer developer API?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, payment-gateway

I was unable to create Developer account for [Payoneer](https://developer.payoneer.com/psd2/user/register), I got this error message:

> The encoding of the certificate in the request is not valid. Check our API documentation for details on valid encoding of the eIDAS certificate.

Before that I made eIDAS certificate with OpenSSL according to this tutorial: [How to generate eIDAS certificate using OpenSSL](https://enablebanking.com/blog/2020/01/13/how-to-generate-eidas-certificate/).

And then I copied the text from eidas.csr file (it was generated by OpenSSL) to the Certificate field when registering an account in Payoneer.

I've searched for tutorials on this but I think I can't found one and it's hard for me to understand. I also can't find it in the payoneer documentation, although there is info like the following text when register account:

> "Check our API documentation for details on valid encoding of the eIDAS certificate."

I also read some answers to a question on Quora: [How can I get an eIDAS certificate for Payoneer?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-get-an-eIDAS-certificate-for-Payoneer), it makes me a little doubt to use Payoneer.